# beamer duplicate slide and no itemize when using columns

Tags: beamer

using the following code in beamer:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{some title}
    some line
    \begin {columns}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics<3>{....jpg}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-3> ...
    \item<2-3> ...
    \item<3> ...
    \end{itemize}

    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

I would expect the left column to appear always when the items run on the right column. What actually happens is that I get a duplicate slide with the text of above the columns, and no the third slide both columns appear - including all the items on the right column at once.
what am I missing?

Comment: With the information you provided so far, I can't reproduce the issue you describe. If I create a compilable MWE from your code fragement, I get the expected output. First slide contains the text above the columns and the first item, the second slide contains the text above the columns, the first and second item and the third slide contains the text above the columns, all three items and the image. A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get would therefore be really helpful.

Comment: I have no idea how to reproduce it in a different way - what I mentioned above is the whole frame

Comment: If I add `\documentclass{beamer}\begin{document}` before and `\end{document}` after your code fragment and replace `....jpg` with `example-image` I get a compilable small document that exhibits exactly the expected output I describedn in my previous comment. Thus, I seem to get a different output than the one you describe. Thus, please prepare such a comlete MWE that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: What does "expect the left column to appear always when the items run on the right column" refer to in this context? Currently the left column contains an image which you inlcluded using `<3>`, therefore it only appears on the third slide. If you want your image to show on all three slides, remove the `<3>` from the `includegraphics` command.

Comment: That's right. the main problem it that other column appears all at once

Comment: Your claims doesn't hold.   See @leandriis answer. Please provide a link to answer where is taken your code that we can see the original code and test it (again).

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

If I take the code you provided in your question and make a compilable MWE out of it, I end up with the following in which the items in the right column are revealed one after the other. I thus can not reproduce the issue "all the items on the right column at once" you describe.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{some title}
    some line
    \begin {columns}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics<3>[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-3> ...
    \item<2-3> ...
    \item<3> ...
    \end{itemize}

    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```